# Dokku use another rsa key

Tags: git, docker, ssh, dokku

can someone clarify if to use dokku need to use another rsa key?

For exemple:

to login to the server we use id_rsa.pub, id_rsa key, right?

I've tried to use the same key to push the repo to dokku and at some point the dokku ask for the password

```
dokku@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:
```

and even added the right password still no log in.

So someone can clarify if we have to create another key just for dokku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a best practice to use a *different* ssh key dedicated to where you want to push.
That way, if one private key is compromised, it is only a problem from *one* remote server access, not *all* of them.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM -P "" -C "dokku access" -f ~/id_rsa_dokku
```

That will generate `id_rsa_dokku.pub` and `id_rsa_dokku`.

Then you need to [register your public key to the dokku server](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/user-management/#adding-ssh-keys).

If you skip that, then SSH would fallback to username/password, which is why you see a password request in your case.

Comment: VonC, thank you for your answer, that is what i did, still requesting the password, so need to restart dokku?

Comment: One observation i disabled root ssh just user with sudo privilege. that can ssh to the server

Comment: @jjplack I confirm: execute all your command without sudo. If sudo is involved, it would not find your user SSH key.

Comment: VonC, ok! and about the /etc/ssh/sshd_config  should add dokku as AllowUsers?

Comment: @jjplack if it is one the remote side, yes. I have seen it, for instance, in dokku installation process like https://github.com/znz/ansible-playbooks/blob/master/roles/dokku/tasks/main.yml#L17

Comment: VonC thank you very much! just left allow the dokku user on sshd_config